# Anyone using JavaSpaces technology?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, javaspaces

Are there real practical uses of JavaSpaces technology out there and how exactly is it implemented?

Answer (score 3):

We are currently using javaspaces (the Sun outrigger implementation), to coordinate loosely coupled processes.  The idea behind it is compelling, and the API is very simple.  The actual implementation has been a problem.  It's built on Jini, so 5 or 6 processes are required to bring up a space.  And, at least in Sun's implementation, there is no way to have it communicate over specific ports, which makes firewalls a bit of a pain.

The other issue that we have run into is that there is no implied ordering in the space.  So if you put 5 objects in, and your template on the read/take matches all 5, it is unspecified which one you will get.  Depending on the application, this may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

[GigaSpaces](https://www.gigaspaces.com/) is a mature version of JavaSpaces.  It is widely used in financial applications, which are kept quiet.

As for the Implementation it is basically an transactional Object database on top of [Jini](http://java.sun.com/products/jini/).  The queries are similar to db4o.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it used in a financial application, mostly for managing compute workers (grid style) where entries were written into the space from front-tier applications and pulled out by workers by matching on a field showing work was needed.  Results could be written back into the space, triggering a `notify` registered by the front-tier app which then reads back the finished piece of work.

For compute workers it's OK, but lack of ordering may be an issue for you (if only because of unpredictability) - some implementations have features to enforce FIFO ordering.  It was also used for long term data storage as it was persistent, but I don't think that was a good idea.  The admin tooling wasn't good enough to make it manageable and performance suffered due to the volume of data.

Dan Creswell's [Blitz JavaSpaces](http://www.dancres.org/blitz/) implementation was used - it's got a good range of features (can run in transient or persistent modes), is designed to be robust (with transaction logging) and retain high performance, and it's very tunable.  As with the other Jini services, you can configure the "exporter" to have it listen on specific ports to make firewalling easier - SSL transports and full PKI were used too and are made possible by Jini's abstraction of communication.

I think Gigaspaces is the only implementation that has continued to innovate by extending the specification in numerous ways, which is nice to see.  They've made it fit a wide variety of use-cases and added implementation features such as clustering and high availability.  Using it would worry me though, as I'd be much happier seeing two or more implementations of these features in the community, given Gigaspaces is fairly proprietary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Orbitz which is a reservation system for hotels runs on Jini.

Based on Java Posse episodes [#82](http://javaposse.com/index.php?post_id=131159), #84 and #86 which is an interview with Vin Simmons this technology is sometimes used in military or financial applications which are unfortunatley on the quiet.

Answer (score 0):

I used it a few years back but it probably has not changed much.

@Keith: It is(used to be atleast) possible to start all the services in a single process/JVM and I think there is documentation out there on how to do this.

I believe Jini/Javaspaces is used in a few large applications (ticketing, cell phones etc) in Europe. Also used by GE Aircraft for research and analysis.

[SORCER lab](http://www.cs.ttu.edu/~sorcer/) at Texas Tech has a large SOA architecture built on top of Jini/Javaspaces and you may be able to find some help there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any new usage of JavaSpaces at this point in time. For distributed computing, most large-scale systems are being built with In-Memory Data Grid technology or partitioned NoSQL-like solutions. (I see a lot of Oracle Coherence being used, but that's probably because I work with it.)

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*